# Mongo Realm + Kotlin error in verifying Class - invalid type 'STRING_LIST'

Tags: mongodb, kotlin, realm

I'm trying to create sample Android Application using Mongo Realm

- Android Studio 4.1.2
- io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:10.3.1
- MongoDB 4.4 Realm

Everything was ok before I added Array "members" to Schema

```
{
  "properties": {
    "_id": {
      "bsonType": "objectId"
    },
    "_partition": {
      "bsonType": "string"
    },
    "title": {
      "bsonType": "string"
    },
    "description": {
      "bsonType": "string"
    },
    "members": {
      "bsonType": "array",
      "items": {
        "bsonType": "string"
      }
    },
    "date_of_trip": {
      "bsonType": "object",
      "properties": {
        "start_date": {
          "bsonType": "string"
        },
        "end_date": {
          "bsonType": "string"
        }
      }
    },
    "trip_icon": {
      "bsonType": "binData"
    }
  },
  "required": [
    "_id",
    "_partition",
    "title"
  ],
  "title": "Trip"
}
```

kotlin class is

```
import io.realm.RealmList;
import io.realm.RealmObject;
import org.bson.types.ObjectId;
open class Trip(
    @PrimaryKey var _id: ObjectId = ObjectId(),
    var _partition: String = "",
    var date_of_trip: Trip_date_of_trip? = null,
    var description: String? = null,
    @Required
    var members: RealmList<String> = RealmList(),
    var title: String = "",
    var trip_icon: ByteArray? = null
): RealmObject() {}
```

And now every time i run app on AVD I get this error

```
2021-03-02 10:50:22.822 6024-6024/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: by.lsd.tripplanner, PID: 6024
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid query: field 'members' in class 'Trip' is of invalid type 'STRING_LIST'.
        at io.realm.internal.fields.FieldDescriptor.verifyColumnType(FieldDescriptor.java:295)
        at io.realm.internal.fields.FieldDescriptor.setCompilationResults(FieldDescriptor.java:261)
        at io.realm.internal.fields.CachedFieldDescriptor.compileFieldDescription(CachedFieldDescriptor.java:95)
        at io.realm.internal.fields.FieldDescriptor.compileIfNecessary(FieldDescriptor.java:303)
        at io.realm.internal.fields.FieldDescriptor.getColumnKeys(FieldDescriptor.java:189)
        at io.realm.RealmQuery.contains(RealmQuery.java:1620)
        at io.realm.RealmQuery.contains(RealmQuery.java:1604)
        at by.lsd.tripplanner.TripsActivity.setUpTripsRecyclerView(TripsActivity.kt:109)
        at by.lsd.tripplanner.TripsActivity.access$setUpTripsRecyclerView(TripsActivity.kt:26)
        at by.lsd.tripplanner.TripsActivity$onStart$1.onSuccess(TripsActivity.kt:47)
        at by.lsd.tripplanner.TripsActivity$onStart$1.onSuccess(TripsActivity.kt:43)
        at io.realm.RealmCache$CreateRealmRunnable$1.run(RealmCache.java:274)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

what is the reason of this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be aware that if your Realm model includes a List and that is a List of primitives, it's not well supported at this time (generally, avoid it).

**EDIT:** Release 10.7 added support for filters/queries as well as aggregate functions on primitives so the below info is no longer completely valid. However, it's still something to be aware of.

The List should be a List of Realm objects whose property is a String.

See the [Relationship](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm-legacy/docs/kotlin/latest/index.html#relationships) section of the documentation under the Lists Of Primitives section

> Lists of primitives do not support lists-of-lists and querying

Comment: Thanks! I changed to "List of Realm objects whose property is a String" and it works now.